# How can I extract the dictionary from the list?

Tags: python

```
shopping_list = {"items": [{"product_id": 1, "price": float(20.1), "quantity": int(5)},{"product_id": 2, "price": 21.2,
"quantity": 3},{"product_id": 3, "price": 33.4, "quantity": 2}] }
```

You need to calculate the subtotal for each item (price * quantity) and then find the total subtotal for all the items in the shopping list:

```
{"items": [{"product_id": 1, "price": 20.1, "quantity": 5,"subtotal": 100.5},{"product_id": 2, "price": 21.2, "quantity": 3, "subtotal ": 63.6},{"product_id": 3, "price": 33.4, "quantity": 2, "subtotal ": 66.8}], "total": 373.5}
```

I'm new to software. I've been trying for a long time and couldn't do it. I have to deliver it tomorrow. It says price and quantity's type is `Nonetype`. How should I do it? Could you help

```
ındex1 = print(shopping_list["items"][0]["price"])

print(type(ındex1))

>><class 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: If this is truly the result, then there is something wrong with `shopping_list`. Try printing it out.

Comment: Provide full code (text not images!) that reproduces the issue.  See [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: The result of `print` is always `None`. Did you mean `ındex1 = shopping_list["items"][0]["price"]`? But why would you call a price `ındex1`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why does the print function return None?](/q/27959258/4518341)

Comment: You've got the extraction correct (`shopping_list["items"][0]["price"]`), but then why are you printing it? If you just remove `print`, this should work properly. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], and check out [ask] if you want tips. See also [How to ask and answer homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341).

Comment: @InSync I guess you missed the `print` in `ındex1 = print(...)`, eh?

Comment: Please don't change the question after it's been posted. I undid your edit. You could ask a new question, but Germano's answer already does exactly what you want, so I don't know what the problem is. If you do end up wanting to ask a new one, please read the links above.

Comment: @wjandrea Right :P Sleepy me.

Answer (score 2):

print() doesn't return anything.
You can calculate the subtotal of each item like this:

```
for item in shopping_list["items"]:
    item["subtotal"] = item["price"] * item["quantity"]
```

Then you can calculate the total with a list comprehension:

```
total = sum([item["subtotal"] for item in shopping_list["items"]])
```

and add it to the main dictionary:

```
shopping_list["total"] = total
```

Comment: You don't actually need to pass `sum()` a list. This works just fine and would be more efficient if `shopping_list["items"]` were very large: `total = sum(item["subtotal"] for item in shopping_list["items"])`

Comment: thank you for your help. So how can I add total and subtotal to the list?